# Multi-function clock GUI

Tags: java, datetime, graphics, processing

I was sitting in my bedroom, looking at my Powers of 2 clock sitting next to my radio, under my analog clock on the wall, and wondered to myself: "Why have all these different clocks when I can have just one?"

So I decided to make my own.  This program contains four different display modes: true binary, BCD, analog, and digital.  If showing BCD or digital the user can select 12- or 24-hour time format.

This was written using [Processing](https://processing.org/), but each of the classes I used for the different clocks are bona fide Java.  The [JavaDoc for the Processing Library](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/) can provide information on the PApplet class used for the basic functions.

If you are interested in running this program, [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9JGyPwakWWES2NPQkxmN3hrb3c) is a link to my sketch folder on Google Drive with an executable, or simply cut and paste everything below into a new Processing sketch and hit run.

To run the source, you will of course need Processing, and the [G4P](http://www.lagers.org.uk/g4p/) library, which can be added via the tool manager.

---

**multi_clock.pde**

```
import g4p_controls.*;

int mode = 0;

GButton[] buttons;
GCheckbox toggle;

AnalogClock analog;
BinaryClock binary;
DigitalClock digital;

void setup() {
  size(340, 300);
  surface.setResizable(true);
  background(50);
  noStroke();

  ellipseMode(CENTER);

  initButtons();

  analog = new AnalogClock(this);
  binary = new BinaryClock(this);
  digital = new DigitalClock(this);
}

/**
 * Initialize GButton objects and 24-hour mode toggle.
 * Each GButton is assigned and event handler and moved
 * to their location for the default view (BCD)
 */
void initButtons() {
  buttons = new GButton[4];

  for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i] = new GButton(this, 0, 0, 60, 30);
    buttons[i].setLocalColorScheme(5);
    buttons[i].setTextAlign(GAlign.CENTER, GAlign.MIDDLE);
    buttons[i].addEventHandler(this, "handleButtonEvents");
  }

  buttons[0].moveTo(20, 20);
  buttons[0].setText("Show BCD");
  buttons[0].setEnabled(false);

  buttons[1].moveTo(100, 20);
  buttons[1].setText("Show Binary");
  buttons[1].setEnabled(true);

  buttons[2].moveTo(180, 20);
  buttons[2].setText("Show Analog");
  buttons[2].setEnabled(true);

  buttons[3].moveTo(260, 20);
  buttons[3].setText("Show Digital");
  buttons[3].setEnabled(true);

  toggle = new GCheckbox(this, 35, 270, 100, 20, "24 Hour Time");
  toggle.setLocalColorScheme(0);
  toggle.setSelected(true);
}

/**
 * Event Handler for GButton objects, called when any button
 * is clicked.  Checks which button triggered the call, and
 * set the mode appropriately. Disable the button that was clicked
 * and enable all others.
 * This also moves the buttons to where they need to be based
 * on the mode.
 *
 * @param source GButton that triggered the event
 * @param event GEvent triggered. By default, only CLICKED, but could
 *              also be PRESSED or RELEASED
 */
void handleButtonEvents(GButton source, GEvent event) {
  for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    if (buttons[i] == source) {
      buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
      mode = i;
    } else {
      buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
    }
  }
  // space the buttons according to width of window
  if (mode == 0 || mode == 1 || mode == 2) {
    buttons[0].moveTo(20, 20);
    buttons[1].moveTo(100, 20);
    buttons[2].moveTo(180, 20);
    buttons[3].moveTo(260, 20);
  } else {
    buttons[0].moveTo(32, 20);
    buttons[1].moveTo(124, 20);
    buttons[2].moveTo(216, 20);
    buttons[3].moveTo(308, 20);
  }
}

// Placeholder for event handler
void handleToggleControlEvents(GToggleControl source, GEvent event) {
}

void draw() {
  // draw appropriate clock
  switch (mode) {
  case 0:
    resize(340, 300);
    toggle.setVisible(true);
    if (toggle.isSelected()) {
      binary.update(hour(),minute(),second(),2);
    } else {
      binary.update(hour(),minute(),second(),1);
    }
    break;
  case 1:
    resize(340, 300);
    toggle.setVisible(false);
    binary.update(hour(),minute(),second(),0);
    break;
  case 2:
    resize(340, 400);
    toggle.setVisible(false);
    analog.update(hour(), minute(), second());
    break;
  case 3:
    resize(400, 300);
    toggle.setVisible(true);
    if (toggle.isSelected()) {
      digital.update(hour(), minute(), second(), 0);
    } else {
      digital.update(hour(), minute(), second(), 1);
    }
    break;
  }
}

/**
 * Resize the canvas, only if new size is
 * different than the current size. This means
 * this function can be called every loop
 * without recalculating the canvas each time.
 *
 * @param w the new width of the window
 * @param h the new height of the window
 */
void resize(int w, int h) {
  if (width != w || height != h)
    surface.setSize(w, h);
}
```

**AnalogClock.java**

```
import processing.core.*;

/**
 * Class containing functions to draw an analog clock.
 * 
 * @author Eric Roch
 * @date 12-13-15
 */
public class AnalogClock extends PApplet {
  private final int CENTER_X = 170;
  private final int CENTER_Y = 230;
  private final int FACE_DIA = 300;

  private final int R_HOUR      =   FACE_DIA * 4 / 15;    /* fractions are not reduced to  */
  private final int R_MIN       =   FACE_DIA * 5 / 15;    /* show the relative lengths     */
  private final int R_SEC_MAJOR =   FACE_DIA * 6 / 15;
  private final int R_SEC_MINOR = - FACE_DIA * 2 / 15;    // short "tail" on second hand
  private final int R_MARK      =   FACE_DIA * 7 / 15;    // hour marks on outside of face

  private final float PI = PConstants.PI;
  private final float TWO_PI = PConstants.TWO_PI;

  private float[] angles;
  private float[][]coords;

  private PApplet parent;

  /**
   * Constructor. Initializes arrays to hold
   * angle and coordinate values so they don't
   * have to be re-initialized every time the
   * clock is drawn.
   */
  AnalogClock(PApplet p) {
    parent = p;
    angles = new float[3];
    coords = new float[3][4];
  }

  /**
   * Render the clock to the canvas.
   *
   * @param h integer hours in 12- or 24-hour format
   * @param m integer minutes
   * @param s integer seconds
   */
  void update(int h, int m, int s) {
    if (!Time.isValid(h, m, s)) {
      print(h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
      println(" is not a valid time. Aborting.");
      return;
    }
    parent.background(50);
    parent.stroke(0);
    parent.strokeWeight(5);

    angles = getAngles(h, m, s);
    coords = getXY(angles);

    // clock face
    parent.fill(255);
    parent.ellipse(CENTER_X, CENTER_Y, FACE_DIA, FACE_DIA);
    parent.fill(0);
    parent.ellipse(CENTER_X, CENTER_Y, 12, 12);

    // dots for numbers
    for (float i = 0; i < TWO_PI; i += PI/6) {
      parent.point(CENTER_X + cos(i)*R_MARK, CENTER_Y + sin(i)*R_MARK);
    }

    // clock hands
    parent.line(coords[0][0], coords[0][1], coords[0][2], coords[0][3]);
    parent.line(coords[1][0], coords[1][1], coords[1][2], coords[1][3]);
    parent.stroke(220, 0, 0);
    parent.ellipse(CENTER_X, CENTER_Y, 8, 8);
    parent.line(coords[2][0], coords[2][1], coords[2][2], coords[2][3]);
  }

  /**
   * Calculate the angles of the clock hands.
   *
   * @param h hour, in 12 or 24 hour format
   * @param m minute
   * @param s second
   * @return array of floats containing the angle of the hours,
   *         minutes, and seconds hands.
   */
  private float[] getAngles(int h, int m, int s) {
    float[] a = new float[3];
    // make the hour hand move a little bit extra each minute
    // PI/6 = (2PI / 12 hrs / 60 min)
    a[0] = map(h % 12, 0, 12, 0, TWO_PI) + map(m, 0, 60, 0, PI/6) - HALF_PI;
    // make the minute hand move a little bit extra every couple of seconds
    // (s/12)*(PI/150) --> s/12 will output {0,1,2,3,4}, dividing the minute into 5 sections
    //                 --> PI/150 = (2PI / 60 min / 5 movements)
    a[1] = map(m, 0, 60, 0, TWO_PI) + (s/12)*(PI/150) - HALF_PI;
    a[2] = map(s, 0, 60, 0, TWO_PI) - HALF_PI;

    return a; 
  }

  /**
   * Create a 2-Dimentional array to hold the coordinates
   * for the clock hands.  Each row in the matrix is a hand,
   * while each column is a coordinate, in the same format
   * as the parameters for @code{Line()}, shown below.
   *   {{x1, y1, x2, y2},  // hours
   *    {x1, y1, x2, y2},  // minutes
   *    {x1, y1, x2, y2}}  // seconds
   *
   * @param a 1-Dimensional array containing 3 values for the
   *          angle (in radians) of the hour, minute, and second
   *          hands, respectively.
   * @return array containing xy coordinates of the hands
   */
  private float[][] getXY(float[] a) {
    float[][] xy = new float[3][4];
    xy[0][0] = CENTER_X;
    xy[0][1] = CENTER_Y;
    xy[0][2] = CENTER_X + cos(a[0])*R_HOUR;
    xy[0][3] = CENTER_Y + sin(a[0])*R_HOUR;

    xy[1][0] = CENTER_X;
    xy[1][1] = CENTER_Y;
    xy[1][2] = CENTER_X + cos(a[1])*R_MIN;
    xy[1][3] = CENTER_Y + sin(a[1])*R_MIN;

    xy[2][0] = CENTER_X + cos(a[2])*R_SEC_MINOR;
    xy[2][1] = CENTER_Y + sin(a[2])*R_SEC_MINOR;
    xy[2][2] = CENTER_X + cos(a[2])*R_SEC_MAJOR;
    xy[2][3] = CENTER_Y + sin(a[2])*R_SEC_MAJOR;

    return xy;
  }
}
```

**BinaryClock.java**

```
import processing.core.*;

/**
 * Class containing functions to draw binaray clocks.
 * Capable of drawing traditional binary, 12-hour binary
 * coded decimal, and 24-hour binary coded decimal.
 *
 * @author Eric Roch
 * @date 12-13-15
 */
public class BinaryClock extends PApplet {
  private final int BOX_SIZE = 40;
  private final int GAP = 10;

  private final int BIN_X = 315;
  private final int BIN_1_Y = 70;
  private final int BIN_2_Y = 150;
  private final int BIN_3_Y = 230;

  private final int BCD_1_X = 15;
  private final int BCD_2_X = 65;
  private final int BCD_3_X = 125;
  private final int BCD_4_X = 175;
  private final int BCD_5_X = 235;
  private final int BCD_6_X = 285;
  private final int BCD_Y = 260;

  private PApplet parent;

  BinaryClock(PApplet p) {
    parent = p;
  }

  /**
   * Render one of the clocks to the canvas.
   *
   * @param h integer hours in 12- or 24-hour format
   * @param m integer minutes
   * @param s integer seconds
   * @param mode select which clock to display:
   *             0-Binary, 1-BCD 12 hour, 2-BCD 24 hour
   */
  void update(int hour, int minute, int second, int mode) {
    if (!Time.isValid(hour, minute, second)) {
      print(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
      println(" is not a valid time. Aborting.");
      return;
    }
    if (mode < 0 || mode > 2) {
      println(mode + " is not a valid mode. Aborting");
      return;
    }

    parent.background(50);
    parent.noStroke();

    if (mode == 0) {    // Straight binary mode
      drawLights(hour, 5, BIN_X, BIN_1_Y, 'x');
      drawLights(minute, 6, BIN_X, BIN_2_Y, 'x');
      drawLights(second, 6, BIN_X, BIN_3_Y, 'x');
    }
    else {
      if (mode == 1) {    // BCD, 12-hour mode
        hour %= 12;
        if (hour == 0) {
          drawLights(1, 2, BCD_1_X, BCD_Y, 'y');
          drawLights(2, 4, BCD_2_X, BCD_Y, 'y');
        } else {
          drawLights(hour / 10, 2, BCD_1_X, BCD_Y, 'y');
          drawLights(hour % 10, 4, BCD_2_X, BCD_Y, 'y');
        }
      }
      else if (mode == 2) {    // BCD, 24-hour mode
        drawLights(hour / 10, 2, BCD_1_X, BCD_Y, 'y');
        drawLights(hour % 10, 4, BCD_2_X, BCD_Y, 'y');
      }
      // Mode 1 & 2 both do this part
      drawLights(minute / 10, 3, BCD_3_X, BCD_Y, 'y');
      drawLights(minute % 10, 4, BCD_4_X, BCD_Y, 'y');
      drawLights(second / 10, 3, BCD_5_X, BCD_Y, 'y');
      drawLights(second % 10, 4, BCD_6_X, BCD_Y, 'y');
    }
  }

  /**
   * Handles the repetitive action of drawing the lights
   * either on or off.  Determines state by extracting each
   * bit from passed integer.  Boxes can be drawn vertically
   * or horizontally, starting with the LSB at the bottom/right.
   *
   * @param var integer variable to display
   * @param n number of bits to extract/boxes to draw
   * @param x coordinate of the bottom/right box
   * @param y coordinate of the bottom/right box
   * @param axis whether to draw the boxes horizontally ('x')
   *             or vertically ('y')
   */
  private void drawLights(int var, int n, int x, int y, char axis) {
    if (axis == 'x') x -= BOX_SIZE;  // convert right edge to left corner
    if (axis == 'y') y -= BOX_SIZE;  // convert bottom edge to top corner

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
      int bit = (var >> i) & 0x1;
      int c = (bit == 1) ? color(50, 50, 255) : color(155);
      parent.fill(c);

      parent.rect(x, y, BOX_SIZE, BOX_SIZE);
      if (axis == 'x') x -= (BOX_SIZE + GAP);
      if (axis == 'y') y -= (BOX_SIZE + GAP);
    }
  }
}
```

**DigitalClock.java**

```
import processing.core.*;

/**
 * Class containing functions to draw a digital clock.
 * Uses PShape objects to create seven segment displays.
 * 
 * @author Eric Roch
 * @date 12-13-15
 */
class DigitalClock extends PApplet {
  private final int HOUR_1_X = 20;    // hour tens
  private final int HOUR_2_X = 110;   // hour units
  private final int MIN_1_X = 224;    // minute tens
  private final int MIN_2_X = 314;    // minute units
  private final int DIGITAL_Y = 100;  // y-value for digital segments 

  private PApplet parent;

  private PShape hSegment = new PShape(PShape.GEOMETRY);
  private PShape vSegment = new PShape(PShape.GEOMETRY);
  private final int[] digits = {
    unbinary("1111110"), // 0
    unbinary("0110000"), // 1
    unbinary("1101101"), // 2
    unbinary("1111001"), // 3
    unbinary("0110011"), // 4
    unbinary("1011011"), // 5
    unbinary("1011111"), // 6
    unbinary("1110000"), // 7
    unbinary("1111111"), // 8
    unbinary("1111011"), // 9
    unbinary("0000000")  // off
  };

  /**
   * Constructor. Initializes PShape objects
   * for drawing seven segment displays.
   */
  DigitalClock(PApplet p) {
    parent = p;
    createShapes();
  }

  /**
   * Render the clock to the canvas.
   *
   * @param h integer hours in 24-hour format
   * @param m integer minutes
   * @param s integer seconds
   * @param mode select whether to display 12- or 24-hour time
   */
  void update(int hour, int minute, int second, int mode) {
    if (!Time.isValid(hour, minute, second)) {
      print(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
      println(" is not a valid time. Aborting.");
      return;
    }
    if (mode != 0 && mode != 1) {
      println(mode + " is not a valid mode. Aborting.");
      return;
    }
    parent.background(50);
    parent.noStroke();

    // 24 hour mode, draw time as reported
    if (mode == 0) {
      drawDigit(hour / 10, HOUR_1_X, DIGITAL_Y);
      drawDigit(hour % 10, HOUR_2_X, DIGITAL_Y);
      drawAM(false);
      drawPM(false);
    }
    // 12 hour mode, display
    else {
      // show AM/PM indicator
      if (hour < 12) {
        drawAM(true);
        drawPM(false);
      } else {
        drawAM(false);
        drawPM(true);
      }

      hour = hour % 12;
      if (hour == 0) {
        drawDigit(1, HOUR_1_X, DIGITAL_Y);
        drawDigit(2, HOUR_2_X, DIGITAL_Y);
      } else {
        // prevent leading zero in hours
        if (hour < 10) {
          drawDigit(10, HOUR_1_X, DIGITAL_Y);
        } else {
          drawDigit(1, HOUR_1_X, DIGITAL_Y);
        }
        drawDigit(hour % 10, HOUR_2_X, DIGITAL_Y);
      }
    }
    drawDigit(minute / 10, MIN_1_X, DIGITAL_Y);
    drawDigit(minute % 10, MIN_2_X, DIGITAL_Y);

    // seconds are not displayed on the clock,
    // but we can use them to flash the separator dots
    if (second % 2 == 0) {
      parent.fill(240, 0, 0);
    } else {
      parent.fill(70);
    }
    parent.ellipse(200, 145, 10, 10);
    parent.ellipse(200, 175, 10, 10);
  }

  /**
   * Initialize segment shapes
   */
  private void createShapes() {
    hSegment.beginShape();
    hSegment.fill(color(0));
    hSegment.vertex(0, 5);
    hSegment.vertex(5, 0);
    hSegment.vertex(45, 0);
    hSegment.vertex(50, 5);
    hSegment.vertex(45, 10);
    hSegment.vertex(5, 10);
    hSegment.endShape(CLOSE);

    vSegment.beginShape();
    vSegment.fill(color(0));
    vSegment.vertex(5, 0);
    vSegment.vertex(10, 5);
    vSegment.vertex(10, 45);
    vSegment.vertex(5, 50);
    vSegment.vertex(0, 45);
    vSegment.vertex(0, 5);
    vSegment.endShape(CLOSE);
  }

  /**
   * Draw the AM indicator.
   *
   * @param enabled whether to draw the indicator "on"=true,
   *                or "off"=false
   */
  private void drawAM(boolean enabled) {
    if (enabled) {
      parent.fill(255, 0, 0);
    } else {
      parent.fill(70);
    }
    parent.rect(40, 230, 10, 10);
    parent.text("AM", 55, 240);
  }

  /**
   * Draw the PM indicator.
   *
   * @param enabled whether to draw the indicator "on"=true,
   *                or "off"=false
   */
  private void drawPM(boolean enabled) {
    if (enabled) {
      parent.fill(255, 0, 0);
    } else {
      parent.fill(70);
    }
    parent.rect(40, 245, 10, 10);
    parent.text("PM", 55, 255);  
  }

  /**
   * Draw a single digit seven-segment display to the screen.
   * Uses an array of integers as a lookup for the binary values
   * for each number. Digits are 67px wide by 123px tall.
   * Segments are illuminated red when on and grey when off.
   *
   * @param val number to be displayed, must be 0-9 or 10 for all segments off
   * @param x x-coordinate of top left corner
   * @param y y-coordinate of top left corner
   */
  private void drawDigit(int val, int x, int y) {
    val = digits[val];    // get the binary value that represents which segments are on

    hSegment.setFill(color(255,0,0));
    vSegment.setFill(color(255,0,0));
    if (((val >> 6) & 0x1) == 1) parent.shape(hSegment, x + 8, y);         // seg a
    if (((val >> 5) & 0x1) == 1) parent.shape(vSegment, x + 56, y + 8);    // seg b
    if (((val >> 4) & 0x1) == 1) parent.shape(vSegment, x + 56, y + 64);   // seg c
    if (((val >> 3) & 0x1) == 1) parent.shape(hSegment, x + 8, y + 112);   // seg d
    if (((val >> 2) & 0x1) == 1) parent.shape(vSegment, x, y + 64);        // seg e
    if (((val >> 1) & 0x1) == 1) parent.shape(vSegment, x, y + 8);         // seg f
    if ((val & 0x1) == 1)        parent.shape(hSegment, x + 8, y + 56);    // seg g

    hSegment.setFill(color(70));
    vSegment.setFill(color(70));
    if (((val >> 6) & 0x1) == 0) parent.shape(hSegment, x + 8, y);        // seg a
    if (((val >> 5) & 0x1) == 0) parent.shape(vSegment, x + 56, y + 8);   // seg b
    if (((val >> 4) & 0x1) == 0) parent.shape(vSegment, x + 56, y + 64);  // seg c
    if (((val >> 3) & 0x1) == 0) parent.shape(hSegment, x + 8, y + 112);  // seg d
    if (((val >> 2) & 0x1) == 0) parent.shape(vSegment, x, y + 64);       // seg e
    if (((val >> 1) & 0x1) == 0) parent.shape(vSegment, x, y + 8);        // seg f
    if ((val & 0x1) == 0)        parent.shape(hSegment, x + 8, y + 56);   // seg g
  }
}
```

**Time.java**

```
/**
 * Static helper class to hold validation and conversion
 * methods relating to time.
 *
 * @author Eric Roch
 * @date 12-13-15
 */
final class Time {
  /**
   * Private constructor to prevent client code from
   * creating an object of this static class.
   */
  private Time() {
  }

  /**
   * Validate time. If hours, minutes, or seconds
   * are outside of the normal range for time, the
   * validation fails.
   *
   * @param h hours in 12- or 24-hour format
   * @param m minutes
   * @param s seconds
   * @return boolean indicating if the time is in
   *                 the standard range
   */
  static boolean isValid(int h, int m, int s) {
    if (h < 0 || h > 23) {
      return false;
    }
    else if (m < 0 || m > 59) {
      return false;
    }
    else if (s < 0 || s > 59) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Take time in 24-hour format and return time in 12-hour
   * format with AM/PM indicator.
   *
   * @param h hours (0-23)
   * @param m minutes
   * @param s seconds
   * @return integer array containing hours, minutes, seconds,
   *         and AM=0/PM=1
   */
  static int[] convertTo12(int h, int m, int s) {
    int[] time12 = new int[4];
    int hour = h % 12;
    if (hour != 0) {
      time12[0] = hour;
    } else {
      time12[0] = 12;
    }

    time12[1] = m;
    time12[2] = s;
    time12[3] = (h >= 12) ? 1 : 0;

    return time12;
  }

  /**
   * Take time in 12-hour format with AM/PM indicator and return
   * time in 24-hour format.
   *
   * @param h hours (1-12)
   * @param m minutes
   * @param s seconds
   * @param isPM integer acting as boolean. AM=0, PM=1
   * @return integer array containing hours, minutes, seconds
   */
  static int[] convertTo24(int h, int m, int s, boolean isPM) {
    if (isPM) {
      h += 12;
      if (h == 24) {
        h = 0;
      }
    }
    else if (h == 12) {
      h = 0;    // 12:00 AM = 0000 hours
    }  

    return new int[]{h, m, s};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me. There's a little bit of copy-n-paste but nothing serious. Good commenting. Thanks for sharing!